# Bootstrap tabs are not acting as expected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to setup bootstrap tabs without javascript (like written here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#markup).

Code copied from bootstrap page:

```
<div>
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Tab 1</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Tab 2</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">Tab 3</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">Tab 4</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Zoker/w6xeyznk/

As you can see, it does not work and I don't know why. Anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included the jquery.js and the bootstrap.js it's important for work because you don't have to code the js part but bootstap already have it.

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes I forgot to include jQuery :)